# Targeting frames from within a frameset

Tags: html, frameset

I have the following frame structure:

```
<FRAMESET rows="25%,75%">
  <FRAME SRC="Banner.htm" BORDERCOLOR ="red" NORESIZE="NORESIZE"/>
    <FRAMESET cols="25%,75%">
      <FRAME NAME="list" SRC="PackageList.htm" BORDERCOLOR="red" NORESIZE="NORESIZE"/>
      <FRAME ID="details" BORDERCOLOR="red" NORESIZE="NORESIZE"/>
    </FRAMESET>
</FRAMESET>
```

I have an HTML page named `kolkata_culture.htm` and also have a tag whose ID is `culture` in the frame named `list`.

Now I want to load the page `kolkata_culture.htm` into the frame having ID `details`
in response to the event of clicking the tag whose ID is `culture` from the frame named `list` and load that frame into the frameset.

How can I do the job through vbscript?

Answer (score 0):

You probably would want to use JavaScript for this, because it works in all browsers (vbscript works only in IE).

You can load frames dynamically from JavaScript (in this example, the frame with the ID "details" will be pointed to a new url):

```
</FRAMESET>
<script type="javascript">
    // load new page into frame (careful; the attribute name is case sensitive)
    document.getElementById("details").setAttribute("SRC", "http://example.com/");
</script>
```

Or from an html event handler:

```
<input type="button" onclick="document.getElementById("details").setAttribute("SRC", "http://google.com/");" >Click me!</button>
```

- Replace «details» with your frame id
- make sure the attribute name is correct (attribute names are case sensitive)
- replace «http://google.com/» with your target url
- replace «Click me!» with your button label

Answer (score 0):

```
<frame name="framename1" src="local.htm" scrolling="no" noresize="noresize" >
<frame name="framename2" src="./http://www.google.com" scrolling="YES" noresize="noresize">
```